# Restrict number of decimals in html5 type="number" input field (with Angularjs model)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Please find the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/q2SgJ/5/

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

      WANTS:  {{val | number:2}} in "input" elelent<br>
    2 decimal in input:  <input  ng-model='val'> <br>
    2 decimal in input:  <input  type="number" step="0.01" ng-model='val'><br>
    2 decimal in input:  <input  ng-model='val' value="{{val |number:2}}"> <br>

  </div>
</div>
```

How can I restrict the decimal places to 2 digits in an INPUT field.  As in the example `{{val | number:2}}` works, but not sure how to use it to format the ng-model attached to an  field. I could have formatted the data/model itself, but I have few values I like to keep the extra decimal, but only display 2 decimal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a directive to control this functionality.  It is not something that ships with angular, but directives can control how things look and work on the page.

I wrote a simple one: http://jsfiddle.net/q2SgJ/8/

This is the linking function that does the trick:

```
   link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
        ele.bind('keypress',function(e){
            var newVal=$(this).val()+(e.charCode!==0?String.fromCharCode(e.charCode):'');
            if($(this).val().search(/(.*)\.[0-9][0-9]/)===0 && newVal.length>$(this).val().length){
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
```

This works at limiting the input to 2 decimal places, but doesn't format the input to two decimal places.  Anyways, it is a starting point.  I am sure you can look up other examples and write your own directive to handle this the way you want.  The thing about Angular is that it is not a framework with an answer to every question, but a framework that allows you to create additional functionality than what HTML5 provides alone and makes it very simple.

Comment: Tim, thanks for confirming it is not natively possible with html5, and also the approach necessary in Angular.

Comment: this directive will stop you entering any values once 2dp has been reached ie. you won't be able to change the numbers to the left of the decimal point

Comment: ^ Agreed. It assumes the user is only entering a number (user input is always right-most), so doesn't handle numbers being edited in any other position.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this without JQuery, and without a directive.  Your original attempt with step was very close.  I found [this site](http://gsferreira.com/archive/2015/02/angularjs-input-number-with-two-decimal-places/) that shows how to use HTML5 inputs to restrict using the step and AngularJS regular expression input filters.

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl"> @*Just an empty controller in this example*@
        <form name="myForm">
            <input type="number" name="myDecimal" placeholder="Decimal" ng-model="myDecimal" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" /><br />
            Is a valid decimal?<span ng-show="!myForm.myDecimal.$valid">{{myForm.myDecimal.$valid}}</span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I expanded on the accepted answer to look at the step attribute when determining how many decimal places to limit.

```
directive('forcePrecision', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
           step: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (!scope.step || scope.step == 'any') {
               return;
            }

            var prec = 1;
            for (var i = scope.step; i != 1; i *= 10) {
                prec *= 10;
            }

            element.on('keypress', function (e) {
                var val = Number(element.val() + (e.charCode !== 0  ? String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) : ''));

                if (val) {
                    var newVal = Math.floor(val * prec) / prec;

                    if (val != newVal) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the Tim's fiddle incase some one is looking for working solution

http://jsfiddle.net/q2SgJ/653/

modified the keypress event to retrieve the original typed value based on the cursor position

```
ele.bind('keypress',function(e){
        var value = $(this).val();
                    var decimalPointPosition = value.indexOf(".");
                    if(!((e.charCode === 46) || (e.charCode > 47 && e.charCode <= 57)))
                        e.preventDefault();

                    else if (decimalPointPosition >= 0) {
                        var decimalCount = value.substring(decimalPointPosition + 1).length;
                        if ((decimalCount == 2 && $(this).prop("selectionStart") > decimalPointPosition)) {
                            e.preventDefault();                     
            }
           }       

        }
```