# Limit input field after 2 decimals in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a number of input boxes on a html page. I want to restrict the user from entering any numbers after 2 decimals.

Comment: Can you discuss what solutions you have attempted so far, what resources you have researched to try and solve your problem, or can you present the current state of your code for further analysis?

Comment: I tried using the below approach,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134391/restrict-number-of-decimals-in-html5-type-number-input-field-with-angularjs-m  and it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guilherme Ferreira described it on his blog:

[Angularjs input number with two decimal places](http://gsferreira.com/archive/2015/02/angularjs-input-number-with-two-decimal-places/)

Create the number input with the number type and step inerval

```
<input type="number" name="myDecimal" placeholder="Decimal" ng-model="myDecimal" *step="0.01" />
```

Set the regular expression to validate the input using ng-pattern. Here I want to accept only numbers with a maximum of 2 decimal places and with a dot separator

```
<input type="number" name="myDecimal" placeholder="Decimal" ng-model="myDecimal" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" />
```

EDIT:

This SO approaches to problem using directive:
[Restrict number of decimals in html5 type="number" input field (with Angularjs model)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134391/restrict-number-of-decimals-in-html5-type-number-input-field-with-angularjs-m)

```
angular.directive('decimalPlaces',function(){
    return {
        link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
            ele.bind('keypress',function(e){
                var newVal=$(this).val()+(e.charCode!==0?String.fromCharCode(e.charCode):'');
                if($(this).val().search(/(.*)\.[0-9][0-9]/)===0 && newVal.length>$(this).val().length){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then use it in your HTML:

```
<input  type="number" step="0.01" ng-model='somemodel' decimal-places>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But the input field still allows me to enter numbers after decimal.

Comment: Take a look at this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134391/restrict-number-of-decimals-in-html5-type-number-input-field-with-angularjs-m

Answer (score -1):

You can use this directive to achieve the same.

```
    .directive('validNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                return;
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (val) {
                var clean = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
                if (val !== clean || val.indexOf('.') != val.lastIndexOf('.')) {
                    if (val.indexOf('.') != val.lastIndexOf('.')) {
                        clean = clean.substring(0, clean.length - 1)
                    }
                }

                if (clean.indexOf('.') != -1) {
                    if (clean.length > (clean.indexOf('.') + 3)) {
                        clean = clean.substring(0, clean.length - 1)
                    }
                }


                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                ngModelCtrl.$render();
                return clean;


            });

            element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```

this directive validates number inputs, and restricts to two decimal points in the input field.